# should we use exceptions in reactor mono flow to match result typings?

Tags: java, mongodb, reactor

I have a situation with strange(?) approach with mongo findOneAndUpdate:
if filter matched - then update, if not - well ok:

```
public Mono<Module> findOneAndUpdateNotificationDate(String moduleId, Duration frequency) {
  Bson filter = and(
    eq(ID, new ObjectId(moduleId)),
    or(
       exists(LAST_NOTIFICATION_DATE, false),
       lt(LAST_NOTIFICATION_DATE, now.minus(frequency))
    )
  );
  Bson updates = combine(
    set(LAST_NOTIFICATION_DATE, now)
  );
  return Mono.from(collection.findOneAndUpdate(filter, updates));
}
```

and service using it:

```
private Mono<Boolean> maybeSendNotification(String moduleId, ModuleState state) {
  return repo.findOneAndUpdateNotificationDate(moduleId, notificationFrequency)
    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new NotFoundException()))
    .flatMap(module -> notificationService.sendAlertEmail(module, moduleState))
    .onErrorResume(NotFoundException.class, e -> Mono.just(true));
  }
```

The goal is to send email notification with some [frequency].

Wonder if the right way to use exceptions here? and how to do it correctly and not to break typings?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, achieved right behaviour just with swap operators and use of Mono.defer:

```
return repo.findOneAndUpdateNotificationDate(moduleId, notificationFrequency)
.flatMap(module -> notificationService.sendAlertEmail(module, moduleState))
.switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> Mono.just(true)));
```